# Opencv: how write a sequence of Mat in an xml using FileStorage

Tags: c++, xml, opencv, mat, file-storage

i'm trying to store a sequence of Mat elements in an xml file. This is a sketch of my code

```
Mat SEQ[3];
int nFrame = 0;
while (1) {
    ...
    ...
    SEQ[nFrame] = dataAt_nFrame;
    if (nFrame == 2) break;
    }

FileStorage fs("test.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "dataSequence" << SEQ;
fs.release();

cvReleaseCapture(&video1);

FileStorage fs2("test.xml", FileStorage::READ);
Mat SEQ2[3];
fs2["sequence"] >> SEQ2;

//.... here i want print out the values in order to check if are the same i've written...
fs2.release();
```

the while(1) analyzes a video, for each frame i obtain an "dataAt_nFrame" which is a Mat. I want to store the entire sequence of these data in an array SEQ (if you could suggest an alternative of the type Mat [] i'll prefer) and then be able to read them and pick each Mat for each frame number.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use byte arrays. [Here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4761/mat-to-byte-array/) is a good example on how to convert cv::Mat to a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `sequences/unnamed collection` for as in example at [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html). Below code doesn't use it though.

```
#include <string>

std::string toString( int count ) {
    return "frame"+std::to_string(count);
}

int nFrame = 0;
FileStorage fs("test.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
while (1) {
    //...
    //...
    fs << toString(nFrame) << dataAt_nFrame;
}

//saving number of frames in file
fs << "frameCount" << nFrame;
fs.release();

//....

int count=0;
FileStorage fs2("test.xml", FileStorage::READ);

//reading number of frames from file
fs2["frameCount"] >> count;
std::vector<Mat> SEQ2(count);

while( --count >= 0 ) {
    //reading individual Mat
    fs2[ toString(count) ] >> SEQ2[count];
}

//...
fs2.release();
```